# In the Catholic Church, is there specific canon law on voluntary excommunication?

Tags: catholicism, canon-law, excommunication

Is there such a thing as voluntary excommunication from the Catholic Church? Maybe a *[latae sententiae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latae_sententiae)* or *[ferendae sententiae](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ferendae_sententiae)?* If there is, how could it be done? Is there some kind of formal process?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll get some answers to your question.

Comment: By "voluntary excommunication" do you mean "excommunicating oneself from the Church" (i.e., apostatizing)?

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing as voluntary excommunication, in the strict sense of excommunication. There's a good [answer by AthanasiusOfAlex](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/33584/1377) which explains the purpose of excommunication; I'll restrict this answer to method, as asked by the question. However, the other answer is valuable in demonstrating that "voluntary excommunication" is absurd.

Excommunication is either *latae sententiae* (imposed by the unlawful act itself) or *ferendae sententiae* (imposed by authority).

Neither of those methods of excommunication is voluntary. An act which incurs a *latae sententiae* excommunication may be voluntary, but the excommunication is not.

If what you are actually asking is about a formal secession from the Church, then yes, any act of formal secession will result in a *latae sententiae* excommunication: [canon 1364](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P52.HTM) specifically mentions apostasy, heresy and schism.

Canon 1365 prescribes a "just penalty" for prohibited participation in religious rites. Canon 1369 prescribes a "just penalty" for public blasphemy, harming public morals or exciting hatred of, or contempt for, religion or the Church. A "just penalty" *could* include excommunication, but it will be *ferendae sententiae.*

All of these acts will be voluntary, but the resulting excommunication is not.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was whether an ordinary could excommunicate himself. But I don't think that's possible. On the other hand, I'm not sure what prohibits it in canon law.

Comment: *whether an ordinary could excommunicate himself* Given that his direct superior is the Pope, the Pope might have cause to offer a ruling if someone tried that.

Comment: Even an ordinary would need just cause. Self-excommunication is absurd.

Comment: Also, excommunication does not strip a person of church office. Perhaps it's sort of like how a SE mod *can* give themselves a suspension.

Answer (score 3):

St. Thomas Aquinas addresses the question of "[Whether a man can excommunicate himself, his equal, or his superior?](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/XP/XP022.html#XPQ22A4THEP1)" in his [*Summa Theologica* suppl. q. 22 a. 4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/XP/XP022.html#XPQ22A4THEP1) c.:

> Since, by jurisdiction, a man is placed above those over whom he has jurisdiction, through being their judge, it follows that no man has jurisdiction over himself, his superior, or his equal, and that, consequently, no one can excommunicate either himself, or his superior, or his equal.